# Help for creating models and associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following ER diagram which I want to convert to RoR models and Associations

[image]

Can someone please help?

Comment: Step 1.  Try something.  Step 2.  When it doesn't work, post what you tried with **specific** question.  We don't want to write you code for you.  But we will help you debug the code you've written.

Comment: I already tried it. And I posted it here.. But noone answered so I deleted my question and I draw a diagram..

Comment: Where's the code?  What problem did you have with the code?  What didn't work?  What errors did you get?  Please post the code and the problems with the code, otherwise there's very little to talk about.

Comment: My code was the same with the code provide bellow except that i had has_many :applications, through :app_permission . My problem was that I don't know how to easily access the fields. For example how can I get the requested permissions for an application?? Application.RequestedPermission.permission ?

Comment: "My problem was that I don't know how to easily access the fields".  Then ask that question as a separate question.  First, however, search because someone may have already asked it.

Comment: ok thanks. I asked a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct translation would be something like:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :default_permission
 has_many :app_permission
end

class DefaultPermission < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :permission
end

class AppPermission < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :application
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :permission
end

class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :requested_permissions
 has_many :default_permissions
 has_many :app_permissions
end

class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :app_permissions
 has_many :requested_permissions
end

class RequestedPermission < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :application
 belongs_to :permission
end
```

Comment: I think there is already such an Application class.. Maybe it should renamed to avoid strange rails behaviour... When you look into your application.rb there si the class called Appliaction..

Comment: Can someone also show an example on how can I get the requested permissions for an application?? Application.RequestedPermission.permission ?

Comment: Well unless you really want an entire model for RequestedPermission. It might be better to not have a model and instead have that an application has_and_belongs_to_many :permissions

Comment: But if I use has_and_belongs_to_many for the AppPermission how can I have a table with 3 other models?